# How to find the row number based on a set of SFC coordinates, in order to pull out the value from another column

Tags: r, sf, string, dplyr

I am new to geodetic data in R, so apologies if this is way off. I have got a dataset, with a column `geometry`, which contains SFC points, and a second column `IntersectingPoints`:

```
IntersectingPoints             geometry
```

```
<list>                      <POINT [°]>
<int [4,415]>      (144.9179 -45.59569)
<int [3,388]>     (5.740768 49.15625)
<int [6,214]>        (2.18701 52.80779)
<int [7,948]>       (3.108628 50.58135)
<int [2,298]>      (-96.77081 37.37828)
```

I would like to input an x and y value, in order to find the row number, which I can then use to pull out the same value from the `IntersectingPoints` column. The code I have written is:

```
x = 144.9179
y = -45.59569
point_ref=st_point(c(x,y))
which(pt$geometry == point_ref)
```

I was expecting this to output the first row, however, this does not work, I think as the geometry is classed as a list.

How I can output the row number?

**EDIT**

The error when trying to run my code was:

```
Error in which(pt$geometry == point_ref) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In which(pt$geometry == point_ref) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.sfc", "Ops.sfg") for "=="
2: In pt$geometry == point_ref :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

When I run `st_sfc(point_ref) == st_geometry(pt),` this does not find any results.

Output for 'st_sfc(point_ref):

```
Geometry set for 1 feature
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 144.9179 ymin: -45.59569xmax: 144.9179 ymax: -45.59569
CRS:           NA
POINT (144.9179 -45.59569)
```

Output for 'st_geometry(pt)' is:

```
Geometry set for 139709 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -172.9813 ymin: -56.81466 xmax: 171.9221 ymax: 71.08403
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
POINT (144.9179 -45.59569)
```

I can see that the points are the same, so I would have thought that when these were run together, a match would have been found!

Comment: "Does not find any results" means "returns a vector of all FALSE values"?

Comment: @Spacedman yeah everything is false, it should return true on the first line, like yours - when I did sqrt(2)*sqrt(2) though, it came out as 2. I am wondering whether it could be due to the setup of the original tibble table - although the outputs above look like I would have expected when running the geomtric values of pt and point ref

Comment: No, if you type in `x = 144.9179` that is **very** likely to not be equal to what *looks like* `144.9179` in the display of the point in your data set.

Comment: I've edited my A to give a fuller example.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an `st_point` object (which is an `sfg` object) with a vector of `st_point` objects wrapped in the `st_sfc` class, which holds metadata about coordinate systems etc. You don't say, but I guess you are getting this error:

```
> point_ref == st_geometry(pt)
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.sfg", "Ops.sfc") for "=="
```

You can turn your `point_ref` into an `sfc` and then compare:

```
> st_sfc(point_ref) == st_geometry(pt)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and that gives a standard R boolean you can use to extract from rows of `pt`, or run `which` on it to get row numbers etc.

HOWEVER....

Doing this is comparing floating point numbers, which is often an ill-advised thing to do. Depending on where your numbers came from, numbers that look equal, or even mathematically should be equal aren't. eg:

```
> sqrt(2) * sqrt(2) == 2
[1] FALSE
```

An example using points would be this. `x` and `xx` look the same:

```
> x
[1] 144.9179
> xx
[1] 144.9179
```

Comparing a point made with `x` and `y` with another point also made with `x` and `y` gives equality:

```
> st_point(c(x,y)) == st_point(c(x,y))
[1] TRUE
```

but with `x` and `xx` fails equality:

```
> st_point(c(x,y)) == st_point(c(xx,y))
[1] FALSE
```

even though these two things look the same:

```
> st_point(c(x,y))
POINT (144.9179 -45.59569)
> st_point(c(xx,y))
POINT (144.9179 -45.59569)
```

The difference is tiny:

```
> xx - x
[1] 9.998757e-11
```

but it will cause equality tests to fail.

Unless your test point is an unmodified subset of your comparison set, you can't rely on equality testing. Example:

Construct 26 points with random coords:

```
> d = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(26), y=runif(26), ID=LETTERS), coords=1:2)
```

Take the 12th point and compare it to all the points. Twelfth value returned is `TRUE`:

```
> p = st_geometry(d)[12]
> p == st_geometry(d)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE
```

But if I look at that point and make a point with those numbers:

```
> p
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.2990404 ymin: 0.005280197 xmax: 0.2990404 ymax: 0.005280197
CRS:           NA
POINT (0.2990404 0.005280197)
> pfail = st_sfc(st_point(c(0.2990404,0.005280197)))
```

it *doesn't* match:

```
> pfail == st_geometry(d)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE
```

The distance is:

```
> min(st_distance(pfail, st_geometry(d))[1,])
[1] 1.727231e-08
```

so if you wanted to test if two points were "the same" you need to test within some threshold to be safe against these kinds of approximations.

See R FAQ 7.31 for more details.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have edited my original post to show you the outcome and the original error. I think it is close to pulling out the index, but it still can't find a match - which I am surprised about as I can see the co-ordinates are the same.

Comment: This is my point about comparing floating point numbers. The numbers may look the same to four decimal places but 1) they might be truncated when printed, and 2) they might be approximated differently because of finite precision decimal representation. Print out `sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)` - it says `"2"`. Is that equal to "2"? No. `sqrt(2) * sqrt(2) == 2` is `FALSE`.